# CSS isn't working?

Tags: html, css

The .css file:

```
#1test {
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
#1test {
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
```

The .html file:

```
<html>
<p id="1test">hey</p><br/>
<p id="2test">idk</p>
</html>
```

I don't get what's wrong with it :/

Comment: Please only post questions here in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You're not including the .css file.
2) An id name cannot start with a number.

Comment: But you can escape a number - https://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/wzueddej/

Comment: @chipChocolate.py But then it doesn't start with a number anymore. Good to know though

Answer (score 0):

Use appropriate names for id and include css in 
html file

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<p id="test1">hey</p><br/>
<p id="test2">idk</p>
</html>
```

css file

```
#test1 {
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
#test2 {
    color:red;
    text-align:center;
}
```